# How to set unique page in one specific store and leave the rest stores with default one?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, cms-pages

I have 4 stores and I'd like to set unique page (lets say I'd want one page to be translated and the others not) to just and only one store. Other stores should have "default" page view.

I've tried to set All Store Views (in Content > Pages) on default one and then add another page with same URL Key but for only one store, but all I've got is error that URL Key already exists.

I'm using Magento 2.1.7

Comment: Content->page->Page in Websites -> select your store

Comment: click on Page in Websites to open store for selecting

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the same action what are you talking about. But when I want to for example set first copy of "404 - Page not found" to all stores and the second one to one specific store it says that URL Key already exists. There is any way to set page to all stores except one?

Comment: i am using this way to select multiple store or except one store. press ctrl to select specific.

Comment: if its helps you. give me upvote to my answer. so its help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content->page->Page in Websites -> select your store 
click on Page in Websites to open store for selecting

if its helps you. give me upvote